# Chef: append to an exsting file from an "erb" template

Tags: chef-infra

Is there a way to append an erb code to a config file:

```
    <% @zookeeper.each_with_index do |ip, id| %>
    <%= "server.#{id}=#{ip}:2888:3888" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a feature Chef supports directly. The `template` resource expects to control the entire file contents. This ensures idempotence and convergence.

Answer (score 2):

### Appending with Chef

You can't append to an existing file with ERB templates in an idempotent way, but you can certainly get the desired behavior with one or more of the following techniques:

1. [Template partials](https://docs.chef.io/templates.html#partial-templates).
2. A [Ruby block](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html).
3. Executing an external shell command like `echo "$somestring" >> outfile`.
4. A line-editing cookbook such as [line](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/line).
5. [An Augeas lens](http://augeas.net/), using a library like [chef-augeas](https://github.com/nhuff/chef-augeas).

### Using Formatted Strings

In addition, while you can't *append* to an existing file managed as an ERB template, you have the option of creating or using multi-line strings in your ERB. Consider the following examples.

#### Iterating Over Values

- /tmp/foo.erb

  ```
  <% # Set up a fixture. This should really be a Chef attribute. %>
  <% @zookeeper = %w[192.168.1.1 192.168.2.2] %>

  <% @zookeeper.each_with_index do |ip, id| %>
    <%= "server.#{id}=#{ip}:2888:3888" %>
  <% end %>
  ```
- example output

  ```
  $ erb -T 2 /tmp/foo.erb 
    server.0=192.168.1.1:2888:3888
    server.1=192.168.2.2:2888:3888
  ```

#### Embed Newlines in Attributes

Alternatively, you might have an attribute with embedded newlines, which you can then translate to multiple lines in the output. For example:

- /tmp/bar.erb

  ```
  <%
    @zookeeper = %w( 
      server.0=192.168.1.1:2888:3888
      server.1=192.168.2.2:2888:3888
    )
  %><%= @zookeeper.join "\n" %>
  ```
- example output

  ```
  $ erb /tmp/bar.erb
  server.0=192.168.1.1:2888:3888
  server.1=192.168.2.2:2888:3888
  ```